# Installing Entity Framework using dnu install - multiple reference issue

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, dnx, system.data

I am developing a Web API using VS Code and DNX. At the moment I am in the need of installing Entity Framework. When I am installing the package using `dnu install EntityFramework` there is no error. It adds the entry `"EntityFramework": "7.0.0-beta4"` in `package.json` file as well as updating `project.lock.json`.

But when I am compiling the application using `dnu build` I am getting the following error message and build fails:

> IHostingEnvironment exists in both Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Abstractions, and Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Interfaces

My DNX version is `4.5.1`

I have no idea about the issue! Someone please tell me how I can get this resolved.

Thanks in advance.

**Update:**

When I remove the entry `"EntityFramework": "7.0.0-beta4"` from `project.json` file, run `dnu restore` and then recompile using `dnu build` it is successful. My guess is there is already an `EntityFramework` installed by default (?) in my application. If it is so, when I add the namespace `System.Data.Entity` in my controller, it is not getting resolved.

The message I am getting is:

> The type or namespace 'Data' does not exists in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [dnx451, dnx451, dnxcore50, dnxcore50]

Doesn't `System.Data` gets installed automatically?

**UPDATE (project.json file)**

```html
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "compilationOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },
  "tooling": {
    "defaultNamespace": "apiservice"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileProviderExtensions": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "System.Net.Http": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
    "Microsoft.Net.Http": "2.2.29",
    "EntityFramework": "7.0.0-beta4"
  },
  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": {},
    "dnxcore50": {}
  },
  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components"
  ],
  "publishExclude": [
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ]
}
```

Comment: This sounds like an issue with your project.json.  Could you post the code?

Comment: Hi Roberto, I have updated my question with `project.json` code.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably remove the Interfaces and just use the Abstractions as this package was renamed.

See announcement: https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/14

Comment: Thanks! Removing those Interface parameters compiles the application. Now I see `System.Data namaespace` is available. But even with `EntityFramework` installed I am not getting `System.Data.Entity` namespace. Why is so?